# Jquery Autocomplete -- working with Firefox 3.6, not with Firefox 5/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, cross-browser

I have a test server with a page using jquery autocomplete.  The autocomplete feature works fine if I connect to the server using Firefox 3.6.  Unfortunately it doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox 5.  Here is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">     
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="/static/css/jquery-autocomplete/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     url = "/autocomplete/";
     $("#searchInput").autocomplete({
         source: url
     });
  });
  </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/site.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function setSearchUrl() {
       searchUrl = "/search/" + document.searchForm.nickname.value + "/"
       document.searchForm.action = searchUrl;
}
//-->
</script>

<h3>Search</h3>
<form
   name="searchForm"
   action="/search"
   method="get"
   onSubmit="setSearchUrl()"
   autocomplete="off">
<input id="searchInput" type="text" name="nickname" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
document.searchForm.nickname.focus();
//-->
</script>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what might be going awry?

*edit:  firebug (in both browser versions) did not show any errors.  Development tools in Chrome did not seem to complain either.*

Thanks!

-Travis

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors in the FireBug console or Chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/AmvsX/

It should get you pointed in the right direction and the setSearchUrl function should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be this line is your offender:

```
document.searchForm.nickname.value
```

What do you get when you type that expression into the console?

Comment: Isn't that line commented out?

Comment: No. He's using (unnecessary) html comments to prevent ancient browsers (e.g. netscape 4) that don't recognize script tags from outputting his code in plain text.

Comment: Wow, interesting, I guess you learn something new every day :)

Comment: Yeah, the internet is a crazy place.

Comment: I deleted the whole script containing 'document.searchForm.nickname.value' but it didn't seem to help. With firefox 3.6, when 'document.searchForm.nickname.value' is typed into the firebug javascript window, as expected, it shows whatever value is in the search box.  I can check firefox 5 tomorrow.

Comment: Firefox 5.0: same result.  document.searchForm.nickname.value is equal to whatever is in the search field.